# Javascript: Recursively count the sum of all elements in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to write a recursive function to count the number of items in a array using Javascript.

I can do it in Python:

```
def count(list):
 if list == []:
  return 0
 return 1 + count(list[1:])
```

How can I do it in ES5 and ES6?

Comment: Is it a two dimensional array? If it isn’t, you could use length().

Comment: Why you need this when you have the [.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property? Note also, that on Javascript `[] == []` is `false`, so you will have to check if `list.length == 0` for the stop condition.

Comment: The title of the question is a little confusing I would suggest you edit it as "Javascript: Recursively count the **number** of elements in array?" Because that's what you want to do according to the body and code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting elements is ridicoulous since you can just take the `length` property. It will be O(1) and do what you expect. As for summing or doing something with the elements:

```js
// recursively. Works only on arrays 
const sumElements = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 1) return arr[0];

  const [e, ...rest] = arr;
  return e + sumElements(rest);
}


// recursively and effiecent. Works only on arrays
const sumElements = (arr) => {
  const helper = (index, acc) => index < 0 ? acc helper(index - 1, acc + arr[index]);
  return helper(arr.length-1, 0);
}


// using higher order functions. Works for all collections that has reduce defined
const sumElements = list => list.reduce((acc, e) => acc + e), 0);

// using iterators. Works for all collections that has iterator defined
const sumElements = (list) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const e of list) {
    sum += e;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most es6-ish, fp-ish way of writing it. Works on all iterables.

```js
const count = xs =>
  xs[Symbol.iterator]().next().done
    ? 0
    : 1 + (([,...xr]) => count(xr))(xs);

console.log(count([1,2,3]));
console.log(count("hello123"));
console.log(count({
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
        yield 4;
    }
}));
console.log(count([]));
console.log(count([1, undefined, 2]));
```

Comment: Just a note, about comparing with `undefined` for the stop condition, what if your input array is `[1, undefined, 3]`?

Comment: @Shidersz yeah that's a bug, thanks for pointing it out. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this as the first option too. After all, this case should not be a problem if the input data can warranty not to have `undefined` values.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to know that `arrays` have a [.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property for this purpose. Knowing this, and if you still wants to get it by recursion, I will do something like next, that uses the [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) and [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). This approach avoid use of `.length` property to detect the stop condition.

```js
const count = (list) =>
{
    let ite = list[Symbol.iterator]();

    if (ite.next().done)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + count(list.slice(1));
}

console.log(count([]));
console.log(count([undefined, null]));
console.log(count([1, 2, undefined, 3, 4]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 recursive function:

```js
const count = arr => arr[0] == undefined ? 0 : 1 + count(arr.slice(1));
console.log(count([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(count([]));
```

ES5:

```js
function count(arr) {
  return arr[0] == undefined ? 0 : 1 + count(arr.slice(1));
}
console.log(count([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(count([]));
```

Comment: Just a note, about comparing with `undefined` for the stop condition, what if your input array is `[1, undefined, 3]`?

Answer (score 1):

## Here's two solutions.

```js
const count1 = ([x, ...xs]) => x ? 1 + count1(xs) : 0
const count2 = (xs) => xs.reduce((y) => y + 1, 0)

console.log(count1([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
console.log(count2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```